# How many consecutive squares can be subtracted from a number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Let's say I am given a number N. I want to check how many consecutive squares of integers(starting from 1) can be subtracted from this number.
Example-
For N=13,
I will first subtract 1(=1^2), leaves 12
I will subtract 4(=2^2), leaves 8
Now I can't subtract next number i.e. 9(=3^2)
Hence answer for this case will be 2.
I want to find a general solution for this problem.
PS: This is not any homework/assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $\;\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^k j^2=\frac16k(k+1)(2k+1)=\frac1{24}(2k)(2k+1)(2k+2)\;$ may help.

The cubic root of $24\,N$ will thus be near of the odd number $2k+1$ (alternative formulation : the cubic root of $3\,N$ would be nearly $\,k+\frac 12$).

To translate this in a numerical algorithm we may use (for $x:=2k+1$) : 
$$\sqrt[3]{x^3-x}\approx x\left(1-\frac 1{3x^2}\right)\approx x-\frac 1{3x}$$
and compute $k$ using :
$$k=\left\lfloor \frac {s+\dfrac 1{3s}-1}2\right\rfloor,\quad \text{with}\;\;s:=\sqrt[3]{24\,N}$$
I'll let you verify all this,

Answer (score 0):

The sum of $k$ first squares is

$$\frac16k(k+1)(2k+1)$$

Since this increases as $N$ does, you "only" have to solve
$$\frac16k(k+1)(2k+1)=N$$

Alas, this is a cubic equation. This makes things a bit difficult, but not impossible. Can you manage?

Comment: Not really helpful. I already knew this sum of first $k$ squares :(

Comment: Roughly speaking, the sum of the first $k$ squares is $k^3/3$, so a first approximation to what you want is $k=\root3\of{3N}$. The actual value of $k$ is surely very close to that number. Try a few examples, and see.